# Angular2 call method of other component

Tags: angular

I have an Angular2 app in which I created an Header component, that's rendered in my main App component.

Now, I have an other Form component that should have its submit button placed in the Header. How could I do that?

I sort of need to communicate between the submit button in the Header and the submit method of the Form component. I know it's trivial to do parent>child or child>parent communication, but in this case there is no parent-child relationship nor sibling relationship between my Header and Form components.

My component tree looks like this:

```
- app-root
  |-- app-header // -> this is where the submit button is
  |-- app-edit-profile
      |-- app-profile-form // -> this is my form
```

Does someone have any idea of a possible implementation?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can create one service which is shared between your header and form component in which you can define `Observable` so that you can subscribe to that `Observable` from form and perform some action when you receive some value from header.

**common.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject }    from 'rxjs/Subject';
@Injectable()
export class CommonService {
  private notify = new Subject<any>();
  /**
   * Observable string streams
   */
  notifyObservable$ = this.notify.asObservable();

  constructor(){}

  public notifyOther(data: any) {
    if (data) {
      this.notify.next(data);
    }
  }
}
```

**header.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

import { CommonService } from './common.service';

@Component({
  selector   : 'header',
  templateUrl : './header.html'
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  constructor( private commonService: CommonService ){
  }

  ngOnInit() {       
  }

  onSubmit(){
    // this method needs to be called when user click on submit button from header
    this.commonService.notifyOther({option: 'onSubmit', value: 'From header'});
  }
}
```

**form.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

import { CommonService } from './common.service';

@Component({
  selector   : 'form',
  templateUrl : './form.html'
})
export class FormComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private subscription: Subscription;
  constructor( private commonService: CommonService ){
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.commonService.notifyObservable$.subscribe((res) => {
      if (res.hasOwnProperty('option') && res.option === 'onSubmit') {
        console.log(res.value);
        // perform your other action from here

      }
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Comment: I've edited my post to add my component tree, as I said there is no parent/child relationship between the two components. However I will try your solution since I guess the service could be shared regardless of the relationship. Thanks!

Comment: You need to declare `CommonService` in your main module's `providers` configuration so that it will share single instance between header and form component.

Comment: Yes, I figured it out, it works like a charm :) Thanks!

Comment: Need to add this to common.services.ts: 
     import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";

Answer (score 2):

Additionally to the solution with the Observable, I think it's important to say something about the EventEmitters as they are, in my opinion, easier to use in this kind of scenarios.

**In the child controller**

import the EventEmitter and the Output types.

`import { EventEmitter, Output } from "@angular/core`

declare an output property of type EventEmitter

`@Output() formSubmit$: EventEmitter<boolean>;`

remember to initialise the EventEmitter in the constructor as follows:

`this.formSubmit$ = new EventEmitter();`

and finally, with a proper action binded to the submit button, trigger the EventEmitter "emit" method to propagate the event across your app:

`this.formSubmit$.emit(true);`

**In the parent Controller**

In the parent's view, bind the formSubmit$ event to an action of the controller:

`<child-selector (formSubmit$)="handleFormSubmit($event)"></child-selector>`

then declare the method in the Controller

```
public handleFormSubmit(submit: boolean): void {
    alert("Form has been submitted! Do your stuff here!");
}
```

Obviously, this kind of strategy can be used **only** when you need to exchange data from a child to a parent controller.

Answer (score 2):

Parent and children communicate via a service

[Angular2 call method of other component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2Xej.png)

Comment: Please add some explanation of what your link is doing. Links can disappear, and therefore, should it be the case, this answer would be worthless.

Answer (score 1):

The use of services and subjects is the easiest way. If you want to keep a record of your data, you can even use replay subject

```
private notify: ReplaySubject<any> = new ReplaySubject<any>();
```

But, you can even try out a library called as eventbus. I have ran into same issues and eventbus is just the right answer for this.