# oncheckbox checked event send data from one component to other componet using event in angular 4

Tags: angular

I have componet1 and component2, component1 has multiple checkboxes and component2 has a group of buttons which is disabled by default.
when I Will check one of the checkboxes among multiple checkboxes then it will send boolean data from componet1 to componet2. using angular 4.

o/p should be =>  Componet2 gets values on every  componet1's checkbox checked event

Sample Code :

```
 constructor( private popsetcardcomponent: PopsetCardComponent) 
 {
    popsetcardcomponent.checking.subscribe(() => {
         this.onCheck(popsetcardcomponent);
    });
 }
```

Comment: create stackblitz here ----->   https://stackblitz.com

Comment: What's the relationship between component 1 and component 2? Are they parent/child? Are they siblings?

Comment: @user184994 they are a sibling.   wait i will create stackblitz.

Comment: you can create one common service as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40400062 with which you can pass data to any other component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve using rxjs **Subject**

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
```

create `commonService.ts`

```
subject = new Subject<any>();
```

and in your `componet1.ts`

```
commonService.subject.next('change');
```

and in your `componet2.ts` subscribe it on **ngOnInit()**

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.commonService.subject.subscribe(res => {
            this.some_var = res;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Eventemitter on the checkbox change event in Component1 and pass the information to the parent component of componet1 and component2. Then you can access the properties and methods from component2 with a ViewChild in the ParentComponent:

component1.ts:

```
@Output checkboxChange: Eventemitter<boolean> = new Eventemitter<boolean>();

changeEvent(){
   this.checkboxChange.emit(value);
}
```

ParentComponent.html:

```
<component2 #component2></component2>
<component1 (checkboxChange)="onCheckboxChange($event)"></component1>
```

ParentComponent.ts:

```
@ViewChild("component2") component2: Component2;
onCheckboxChange(value: boolean){
  this.component2.doWhatYouWantWithCheckboxValue(value);
}
```

Comment: @Bhosale said his components are siblings, then how you can use Output decorator..???

Comment: When they are siblings the have a common parent component, where they are placed in. Or do I misunderstood there something? Correct me if I'm wrong.